# So confused about why vars work sometimes with or without var?

Tags: javascript

I am really confused as to why sometimes vars will not work when "var" is declared in front of them when used in a namespaced object. Isn't adding "var" in front of every variable the correct thing to do to keep it outside the global namespace?

Or would creating any var without declaring "var" first in my namespaced object, ensure of this, so I don't eed to worry about "var"?

Here's an example of my code:

```
MYNAME.DoStuff = {
   initialize: function() {
       var var1 = 'name'; //1
       var2 = 'name'; //2
       this.var3 = 'name'; //3

       var $var4 = $('#' + name); //4
       $var5 = $('#' + name); //5
       this.$var6 = $('#' + name); //6
   },

   linkStuff: function() {
       // then use the vars from the init above in here
   }
}

MYNAME.DoStuff.initialize();
```

Can someone tell me which number (1, 2, or 3) is correct? Are there cases where I would use more than one or all? How about when I need to do DOM references with jQuery? Which way is correct (4, 5, or 6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` statement will bind the variable to the scope of the current function, in your example `var1` is accessible only within `initialize`.

Your second example, `var2 = 'name';` is simply an assignment made to a -possibly- *undeclared identifier*.

This is an *anti-pattern*, and should be avoided. If the identifier is not resolvable higher in the scope chain, `var2` will end up being a property of the global object -an implied global, since most of the time you actually try to avoid globals-.

Moreover, the new ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode, completely disallows this kind of assignments, *please* avoid them...

The third example, `this.var3` will create a *property* in the *current* object, in your example the `this` value of `initialize` will refer to `MYNAME.DoStuff` because you invoke the initialize method by `MYNAME.DoStuff.initialize();`.

In this third example you can access this kind of properties on your `linkStuff` function, just by `this.var3` - if you invoke that `linkStuff` function properly, e.g. `MYNAME.DoStuff.linkStuff();`-.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it looks like you're trying to do in the `linkStuff` method, you might try this:

```
var DoStuff = {
    firstVar: null,
    secondVar: null,

    initialize: function() {
       // set initial values
       this.firstVar = 'name';
       this.secondVar = 'name2';
    },

    linkStuff: function() {
        alert(this.firstVar);  // 'name'
    }
};
var myname = DoStuff;
myname.initialize();
myname.linkStuff();
```

Comment: So what if I wanted to do a DOM reference to an element using jQuery when defining a variable? Take for example firstVar, would I need to change this.firstVar = 'name'; to this.$firstVar = $('#name');? That seems to be what's working for me currently when I need to re-use variables in methods down the script, but it just looks weird seeing this.$firstVar. I just want to figure a good way out to not have to use jQuery to get an element 5x and just get it once at the top of the script.

Comment: Using $ as a prefix to variables that hold a jQuery object is common practice, so I understand why you want to use it. Yes, `this.$firstVar` does look weird, but you might get used to it. If you don't, you can always prefix it with something else: this.j_firstVar, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As @CMS pointed out, `var` sets up a variable in the current scope. That's why you do `var variablename` *outside* of functions to create *globals* and `var variablename` *inside* functions to create *locals*.

But in the context of objects, there's more going on. Javascript has a feature called closures, which enables very powerful tricks like [private, public and privileged methods](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) (I don't normally like linking to Crockford because he's a bit of an arrogant knob, but sometimes he's a smart knob).

The other thing to watch out for is that Javascript objects are actually very different from objects in most other languages. In Javascript, you don't define them, you build them. If you do something like this:

```
function stuff() {
   // Do init code here

   this.linkStuff = function() {
        // Do linkstuff code here
   }
}
```

... you can do `myname.dostuff = new stuff()` and your initialization code will run automatically. That is also the point to fetch a jQuery object and assign it to a variable for later use.